# 500 Error When Migrating To Drupal 8

Tags: upgrade, drupal-8

I have followed the great instructions on the question  *[Can I upgrade a drupal 7 + civi site to drupal 8?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28655/can-i-upgrade-a-drupal-7-civi-site-to-drupal-8/28656#28656)* but I am running into a road block. The first time I loaded Civi it loaded without my database but I fixed the config file and now I can tell from cv that it is loading my database but in the browser I get a 500 error.

I am seeing these two errors in the logs and I have verified there is more than enough memory allocated.

```
[Tue Jun 09 22:58:19.026852 2020] [php7:error] [pid 20039:tid 140003429107456] [client 73.95.227.117:53058] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1317011456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 803225600 bytes) in /var/www/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 520

[Tue Jun 09 22:58:19.027004 2020] [php7:error] [pid 20039:tid 140003429107456] [client 73.95.227.117:53058] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1317011456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 803209216 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the out of memory problem see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/119 and the workarounds in there, which should then allow logging the actual problem.

Also that stackexchange article is old and a bit out of date, although the gist of it is right. But you might want to use [this method](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/35608/181) instead of roundearth, and the civicrm.settings.php entries are a little different from the roundearth one. The other method should set the civicrm.settings.php settings for you.